# Capture photo with camera and store in DB Phonegap

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I am trying to build an app using Phonegap (Cordova 2.2). I am fairly new to code and js in particular so please be patient if some of my questions seem daft. My question has a few parts:
I want the user to be able to enter name and image (using the device camera) to create their profile. I have tested on the emulator and so far they can enter their name and get take a photo with camera. These both display in the  emulator on completion. However, obviously I want to save that detail, so, I have created a DB (from reading, local storage is limited  in size). 
1. Is the database done correctly? I am getting neither error nor success alerts.
2. I am struggling with the logic of how I pass the information into the database. I'm guessing that I call the populate_UsersDB() function on a click event and need to write some sort of INSERT INTO userProfiles VALUE something. Also, can I grab the Imagedata directly from the onPhotoFileSuccess() function and send it into the database from there. 
3. If I don't want to have a done button (rather have a 'Tap here to take picture' placeholder), how do I test that the action is complete and send the info to the db. From reading, I think I can use onChange(), but not sure. Also, guessing I  have to use post or get somewhere?

Sorry, I know there is a lot of questions within this question. Any advice or support is greatly appreciated. Thanks. Here's the code.

```
    //Use the device camera to capture an image of the user
```

var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

```
// Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// PhoneGap is ready to be used!
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  // Get image handle
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
function onPhotoFileSuccess(imageData) {
  // Get image handle
  console.log(JSON.stringify(imageData));

  // Get image handle
  //
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  smallImage.src = imageData;
}

// A button will call this function
function capturePhotoWithData() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality:50, destinationType:Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL });
}
function getPhoto(source) {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}

// Called if something goes wrong.
function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

//CREATE THE DATABASE
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    var db = window.openDatabase("Users_DB", "1.0", "User Profiles DB", 200000); //will create database or open it

    //function will be called when device ready
    function onDeviceReady(){
        db.transaction(populateUsers_DB, errorCB, successCB);
    }
    //create table
    function populateUsers_DB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userProfiles (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT NOT NULL, Image BLOB)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO userProfiles(Name) VALUE ("")');
    }
    //function will be called when an error occurred
    function errorCB(err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }
    //function will be called when process succeed
    function successCB() {
        alert("success!");
        db.transaction(queryDB,errorCB);
    }
    //select all from userProfiles
    function queryDB(tx){
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM userProfiles',[],querySuccess,errorCB);
    }
    function querySuccess(tx,result){
        $('#userList').empty();
        $.each(result.rows,function(index){
            var row = result.rows.item(index);
            $('#userList').append('<li><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+row['Image']+'</h3><p class="ui-li-desc">Name '+row['Name']+'</p></a></li>');
        });
        $('#userList').listview();
    }
```

Comment: Original heading was misleading  a  whole different issue. Changed.

Comment: why you want to save the image in the db? Isn't it a nicer way to save the image on the file system (and if needed deposit the path in the db)?

Comment: @Inkers : Have you got this working, as I am also looking for similar type of scenario?

Comment: Hi Mrunal, Sorry for late reply. I haven't been on here. I don't have this code to hand and will be more than a week or more before I can get my hands on it. I presume you have found solution by now.